# Plotly.js: Initial Zoom

Tags: plotly

I have 256 data points. When the plot first appears I'd like the x axis to be automatically zoomed to a specific range along the X axis. Is there a way? Must I punch down to D3 somehow?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Something like:

```
Plotly.plot('graph', [{
  /* some data trace */
}], {
  xaxis: {
    range: [0, 1]  // to set the xaxis range to 0 to 1
  }
});
```

More info in the plotly.js [chart attributes reference](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-range).

Comment: Thanks. I feel a little silly that I couldn't figure that out.